# improve Tensorflow.support.task to be able object tracking

Tags: python, tensorflow, object-detection-api, object-tracking

I want to improve my code on object tracking. But TensorFlow Lite's Task Library doesn't currently offer a dedicated object tracking API,I might be able to leverage lower-level components like the ObjectDetector class and combine it with custom tracking logic.
This approach requires more manual implementation but provides greater control over the tracking process. anyone have source to read or code on implement this? thank u before hand

Answer, source code,..

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.